# Support multiple assemblies on ASP.NET\C# projects

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, c#-4.0, dll, .net-assembly

We're developing a ASP.NET application and having some problems with integration with a MS dll (Microsoft.AnalysisServices)?

The original project was linked to the dll which came with SQLServer2005 (Version=9.0.242.0). After migrating to SQLServer2008R2 (version=10.0.0.0) we encountered this problem:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AnalysisServices,
>   Version=9.0.242.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91'
>   or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file
>   specified.

This is understood since we compile the project with one version and then another version is located on the server. After installing SQLServer2008R2 on the development machine the problem was fixed.

However we now have another problem that we need to support both SQLServer2005 and SQLServer2008R2 environments. I know that we can redirect the search path for the dll using a config file (that it will search for a different version that what it was compiled with), but I can't seem to find instructions how to use it for Web Application (on w3wp). We tried to use "Specific Version"=false, but since this is a "Strong Name" assembly it doesn't work as one would think.

The relevant link which I found is this:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlanalysisservices/thread/47d0b992-3c10-4851-b2a5-9f72d2c0976e

Can someone please direct me to a link for solving this issue?

Update: I guess I didn't test it correctly since it doesn't work for other servers in SQLServer2008 R2. I guess you can't use range in the newVersion element. So the question is still opened for everyone! . Bottom line is that I know that I have version 9.0.242.0 but the customers version may be either 9.0.242.0 or 10.0.0.0. Is there a method which I can dynamically choose the correct assembly on the production server

Answer (score 0):

You can hook into AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve and load the assembly you want. If you return null it will look for it normally.

eg.

```
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += Resolve;

    private static Assembly Resolve(object source, ResolveEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.Name.StartsWith("Microsoft.AnalysisServices,"))
            return Assembly.LoadFile("Microsoft.AnalysisServices.dll");
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try adding a bindingRedirect to your web.config.